# Template base class accessible when inheriting from a specific specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, language-lawyer, template-meta-programming

The other day, I discovered that this was possible:

```
template <class T> struct base {};
struct derived: base<int> {};

int main()
{
    // The base class template is accessible here
    typename derived::base<double> x;

    // from the comments, even this works
    typename derived::derived::base<double>::base<int>::base<void> y;
}
```

I have no recollection of ever reading this on cppreference or in C++ tutorials, or this being exploited in clever template metaprogramming tricks (because I'm sure it can be). I have several questions:

- Does this thing have a specific name?
- Where is it documented in the C++ standard and on cppreference?
- Is there any template metaprogramming trick exploiting this?

Comment: Note that `base<double>` isn't a base class of `derived<int>`.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here? There's an irrelevant namespace on `base` and template type on `derived`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't think this is an attempt at accomplishing anything. Rather it's a curious observation. Where you would expect to need to qualify `base<double>` with the namespace `space`, in this example using `derived<int>` seems to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: People are essentially accessing some nested type when using stuff like `std::enable_if<>::type`. Same thing. Upd: not only base, but self class is also accessible: so you can write like `typename derived::derived::derived::derived::base<double>::base<double>::base<double>::base<double> x;`

Comment: @MarkRansom Yeah, I'm not trying to accomplish anything (yet :p). It just seems very weird to me...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does C++ syntax “A::B:A {};” mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546616/what-does-c-syntax-aba-mean)

Comment: Isn't this a dupe? I feel like the fact at least that the `derived` can be repeated has been discussed multiple times on SO.

Comment: @NirFriedman That's not really the point of the question though.

Comment: FYI, clang gives the following warning, which makes me think this isn't legal c++: `<source>:7:57: warning: ISO C++ specifies that qualified reference to 'base' is a constructor name rather than a template name in this context, despite preceding 'typename' keyword [-Winjected-class-name]
    typename derived::derived::base<double>::base<int>::base<void> x;` with an arrow pointing at the start of the last `base`.

Comment: @NirFriedman Only on Clang 5.0 and above (Clang 4.x does not give any warning). Hopefully other compilers fix this soon.

Comment: The simpler version seems to throw out some of the utility here, in that `base` is no longer in a remote namespace.

Comment: [\[temp.local\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local), [\[class.qual\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.qual#2)

Comment: @cpplearner Why didn't you write an answer?

Comment: So you're surprised that the name `base` is defined in the context of `derived`? I never thought about it but it makes sense that it would be. What really surprises me is @NirFriedman's note that it names a constructor function and not a type; normally constructors can't be called by name.

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't know what's going on here, the rabbit hole seems pretty deep to me: https://godbolt.org/g/N2PFv6.

Comment: @NirFriedman That warning is unjustified, because in a `typename` specifier, functions are ignored (IIRC).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @Nir Friedman in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268883/template-base-class-accessible-when-inheriting-from-a-specific-specialization#comment83521769_48268883), `typename derived::derived::base<double>::base<int>::base<void> y;` might actually be ill-formed because `derived::derived::base<double>::base<int>::base` is treated as a constructor of `base`, per [[class.qual]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.qual#2).

---

> - Does this thing have a specific name?

It is called *injected-class-name*.

> - Where is it documented in the C++ standard and on cppreference?

In the standard: [[class]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#2) specifies that the name of a class is treated as if it were a public member of that class. [[temp.local]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.local) specifies that the injected-class-name of a class template can be used as either a *template-name* or a *type-name*.

On cppreference: it is (incompletely) documented in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Injected_class_name.

> - Is there any template metaprogramming trick exploiting this?

I'm not aware of any such tricks, though in everyday use, injected-class-name is employed whenever the current class is named in the class definition:

```
template<class T>
struct A {
    A<T>& operator=(const A<T>&); // injected-class-name as template-name
    A& operator=(A&&); // injected-class-name as type-name
};
```

The latter may be deliberately used to shorten member declaration.

The injected-class-name of a base class is mostly used (unconsciously) in a member initializer list:

```
struct B : A<int> {
    B() : A() {}
};
```